# Symfony 1.4 Task : include all librairies folders from apps/frontend/lib

Tags: symfony-1.4

I generated a task with `php symfony generate:task myTask`.

The generated file `myTaskTask.class.php` is located in the `app/lib` folder of the Symfony application.

**In this class, I want to use all the classes from an other folder located in `apps/frontend/lib`.**

How can I do to this?

I'm looking for a solution since a long time but I didn't resolved the problem. 
I tried with `autoload.yml` file but it doesn't work, and it's not a good solution to do a `require_once` for each file because there are too many classes.

Comment: Have you looked at the `application` option of the task?

Comment: @VladJula-Nedelcu : yes I have looked at this. Maybe I'm wrong but I didn't find nothing that could solve my problem.

Comment: if you're running your task with `--application=frontend` everything in the `frontend` app should be available to you

Comment: @VladJula-Nedelcu : indeed you're right it works correctly! Thanks for your help. I've just found an other solution : add this line `$conf = sfApplicationConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', true);` in the `execute` function

Comment: If this works you can provide this as an answer and accept it. Maybe this will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 solutions to solve the problem :

- run the task with `--application=frontend`:

  ```
  php symfony project:myTask --application=frontend
  ```
- or add this line at the beginning of the `execute` function of the task :

  ```
  $conf = sfApplicationConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', true);
  ```

With these solutions, everything in the `frontend` app is available from the task's class.

Comment: The first one is **really** recommend instead of the second one.